# Crawl to the lazyloaded class I changed the src of the img tag

Tags: python, web-crawler

How to get the correct src of the product. I use Python's Requests and BeautifulSoup for crawl, but the data has been changed to a different src because that class contains lazyloaded in the Img tag, half of the product I crawled is okay but the other half contains lazyloaded in the back of the class. Here is my result changed to

```
 data:image / svg + xml,% 3Csvg xmlns = 'http: //www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
 viewBox = '0 0 1 1'% 3E% 3C / svg% 3E
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot tell what you asking.   What are you trying to do, and what isn't working?

Comment: Hello. I mean my src crawl has been changed, since the IMG tag's class contains lazyloaded. In the page I crawled only the second half contained the lazyloaded class, the src didn't matter, but when I crawled it changed, I don't understand why.

Comment: @TimRoberts Please help me, I haven't solved the problem yet

Comment: Changed from what?  `requests` grabs the initial HTML content of a page.  It doesn't run any Javascript.  Nothing can change.  No callbacks will run.  Nothing is "lazy loaded".  If the image isn't filled out in the initial load, you won't get it.  If you need to let Javascript run, you'll have to use a real browser, like `selenium` or `request_html`.